# ggplot2 error after upgrade to version 2.0

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some code that no longer works since upgrading to the latest ggplot2 version. It's been out since early December and I'm wondering if anyone else has the same problem.

The following code used to work perfectly:

```
gLM1 <- ggplot(data = raw.data, aes(x = predict.lm1, y = (Sales_C-predict.lm1))) +
geom_point(alpha = I(0.75), colour = myPal[1]) +
geom_smooth(span = 0.75, degree = 1, size = 1.25, se = FALSE, colour = myPal[5]) +
labs(list(title = "Fitted vs Residuals", x = "Fitted Values", y = "Residuals")) +
theme_bw() + myGgTheme
gLM1
```

Now is suddenly returns this:

> Error: Unknown parameters: degree

It works again if I remove the degree parameter from the geom_smooth.
Similarly, this code used to run and now fails:

```
gclus <- ggplot(data = raw.data, aes(x = oOrollingSD, y = OnTarget, colour = clusterGroup, size = Quota)) +
xlim(4.2, 11.8) +
geom_point(alpha = I(0.75)) +
geom_vline(x = 7.8, linetype = "dashed", colour = myPal[3]) +
scale_colour_manual(values = myPalContrasts[c(7,3,4)]) +
theme_bw() + myGgThemeSilentX
gclus
```

The error is

> Error: Unknown parameters: x

It works again if I remove the `geom_vline` (I can't simply remove the x parameter here as that is what makes the vline position!

All this code was working correctly until yesterday. I ran it literally dozens of times in the last few weeks preparing a report. I read about the latest release of ggplot2 and updated it yesterday and these errors have appeared.

My ggplot2 version is 2.0, all my other session info is below. I don't recall what ggplot2 version I was on before:

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Singapore.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_Singapore.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_Singapore.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=English_Singapore.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[6] methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.4.3     readr_0.1.1     stringr_1.0.0  
[4] knitr_1.11      ggplot2_2.0.0   lattice_0.20-33

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.1      digest_0.6.8     assertthat_0.1  
 [4] R6_2.1.1         grid_3.2.2       plyr_1.8.3      
 [7] gtable_0.1.2     DBI_0.3.1        magrittr_1.5    
[10] scales_0.3.0     highr_0.5.1      stringi_0.5-5   
[13] lazyeval_0.1.10  curl_0.9.3       rmarkdown_0.8.1 
[16] labeling_0.3     tools_3.2.2      munsell_0.4.2   
[19] parallel_3.2.2   colorspace_1.2-6 htmltools_0.2.6
```

Comment: you not the only one :) but without your data it's hard to help, but look at new doc page http://docs.ggplot2.org/dev/theme.html

Comment: I don't see a promise in the docs that the triple dot mechanism will pass the degree parameter to the `loess` machinery.

Comment: thanks to everyone who contributed. it is now fixed as per the guidance from Baptiste

Answer (score 8):

from the docs,

1- use `method.args` to pass further arguments to the modelling function

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
 geom_point() +
 geom_smooth(method = "loess", method.args=list(degree=2))
```

2- the relevant aesthetic is xintercept

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point() + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = 5)
```